# compare arrays one by one

Tags: php, arrays

I have this output of arrays when I print_r 
The array from database

```
$answer --> Array ( [id] => 251 [question_id] => 242 [text] => something 
 [order] => 4 [deleted] => 0 )
```

and the array that comes what user selectes

```
//Array ( [0] => 254 [1] => 251 [2] => 252 [3] => 253 )
```

I need somehow to compare every answer that comes from db `[id]=>251 to compare with [0] => 254`what can I use, array_diff or intersect or another function, thank you

Comment: use loop according to your requirements

Comment: You can use `array_values($answer )` it return array with integer index. so you can compare easily using a loop.

Comment: simple use in_array `in_array($answer['id'],$selects);`

Comment: Your question seems unclear to me, please post your expected result and explain why it is the expected result (and what you are logically trying to accomplish with this task).

Answer (score 1):

simple use `in_array` function searches an array for a `specific` `value`

```
in_array($answer['id'],$selects);
```

Answer (score 0):

You can use [array_filter](http://php.net/manual/en/function.array-filter.php) to filter the answers from db:

```
$myAnswers = array_filter($answers, function($answer) use ($selectedAnswers) {
    return in_array($answer['id'], $selectedAnswers);
});

var_dump($myAnswers);
```

Answer (score 0):

Try This simple one

```
$answer = array('id'=>'251','question_id'=>'242','order'=>'4','deleted'=>0);
$answerArray  = array('254','251','252','253');

foreach ($answerArray as $key => $value) {
        if($answer['id'] == $value){
            echo "Right answer is". $value;
        }
}
```

Hope it helps!

Comment: thanks but I am on a foreach loop for $answer like this:     foreach($question_answers as  $answer){
                    

 foreach ($user_answer as $key => $value) {
                    $value;
                     if($value == $answer['id']){
                        echo "ok ===>" .$value . "<br>";

                     }else{
                        echo "no   -------------------------------- >" .$value . "<br>";
                     }
                 }  and it is showing to many answers

Comment: why are you using two foreach loops see my answer

Answer (score 0):

You can use array_search

Like that

```
$answer = Array ( 
    "id" => 251,
    "question_id" => 242,
    "text" => "something",
    "order" => 4,
    "deleted" => 0 
);

$ids= array(254,251,252,253);

$key = array_search($answer["id"], $ids);

if($key){
    echo "Find - Key: " . $key . " and ID: " $ids[$key];
}
```

Answer (score 0):

If your $answer array is multidimensional array the you can find the prent ids like this

```
$data= [['id' => 251 ,'question_id' => 242 ,'text' => 'something','order' => 4 ,'deleted' => 0 ]];
$selectors=[254,251,252,253];
$presentIds=[];
foreach ($selectors as $selector){
    if(in_array($selector,array_column($data,'id'))){
        $presentIds[]=$selector;
    }
}
```

Here `$presentIds` hold all the present ids.

Answer (score 0):

I created a function for check question id. Hope it will be useful

```
function checkAnswer($question1, $question2) {

    $indexed_array1 = array_values($question1);
    $indexed_array2 = array_values($question2);

    if ($indexed_array1[0]==$indexed_array2[0]) { // for check the answer && $indexed_array1[n]==$indexed_array2[n] | if the answer index is 'n'
        return true;
    }
    return false;
}
```